# Conditional sum based on indicator

Tags: r, sum, data-manipulation

I have a data frame like this:

```
   A   B   Ind
1 10   8     1
2  9  10     2
3  7   1     2
4 19  20     1
5  .   .     .
```

How can I sum the columns based on the `Ind` value? If `Ind==1`, sum from column `A`, if `Ind==2`, sum from column `B`. For example, the output for the first 4 rows should be `10+10+1+19=30`, where the first 10 is in `A`, second 10 is in `B`, third 1 is in `B` and fourth 19 is in `A`.

Comment: I know this can be done by a for loop + if statement. Is there a way to do this quickly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option using `I`

```
 sum(with(dat,A*I(Ind==1)+B*(Ind==2)))
```

Comment: Interesting use of `I`. Wouldn't have occurred to me here. +1

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your data.frame is called "mydf", you can use `ifelse` as follows:

```
sum(with(mydf, ifelse(Ind == 1, A, B)))
```

Here's the result of the `ifelse` part:

```
> with(mydf, ifelse(Ind == 1, A, B))
[1] 10 10  1 19
```

Of course, if you have more than one condition, you can nest them as necessary.

---

Here is a more verbose alternative that uses basic subsetting:

```
sum(with(mydf, c(mydf[Ind == 1, "A"], mydf[Ind == 2, "B"])))
```

Comment: The last line does not return exactly. If you generate the data by this line: `mydf <- data.frame("A"=c(1,22,1,2,106,0),"B"=c(0,0,4,0,44,4),"Ind"=c(1,1,2,1,1,2))`, and `with(mydf,c(mydf[Ind==1,"A"],mydf[Ind==2,"B"]))` won't give you 1,22,4,2,106,4. Instead, it gives you 1,22,2,106,4,4.

Comment: @Boxuan, you don't mention anywhere that the *order* in which the values appear is important, and as far as I recall from my math classes, it doesn't for addition.

Comment: You are definitely right. The order is not important. I am just curious why the `with` function does not return the rows in order.

Comment: @Boxuan, it's not the `with` function that you should be looking at. All three suggestions use `with` purely for convenience of not having to repeatedly type the `data.frame` name. The second option I show basically appends two subsets together, which is why the order is not preserved. agstudy's solution adds two vectors together, where several of the values in each would be zero, and `ifelse` proceeds down the `data.frame` by row. Thus, the `ifelse` and `I` solutions would preserve the row order, but the subsetting version won't.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `which`:

```
sum( df$A[which(df$Ind==1)] , df$B[which(df$Ind==2)] )
```